# How to serve one image at multiple urls in Laravel

Tags: image, laravel

I manage a Laravel (Laravel 4.2 on Apache) web site that serves images for 'items' at a url like the following:

```
http://<domain>/images/<item-key>/<img-name>
```

We are trying to work with another organization to pull information from our site, and they are requiring our images to have one base url for all images instead of one base url for the images for each item.  So we need to have a URL something like this:

```
http://<domain>/image_base/<item-key>-<img-name>
```

Is there a good way to allow for both url formats to be used for any item image?  My first attempt used a redirect so that using the latter url redirected to the the former, but apparently that is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes:

```
Route::get('images/{item-key}/{img-name}', 'ImageController@show');
Route::get('image_base/{item-key}-{img-name}', 'ImageController@show');
```

In your controller:

```
public function show($key, $name)
{
    // Show image
}
```

Where `ImageController@show` is your controller and method, both should be the same, as you are passing the same variables to it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting, I was able to return a regular Laravel Response from my controller, as in:

```
$response = Response::make(File::get($image_path), 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', File::type($image_path));
```